# Springboot Dynamically modify the ResourceHandlerRegistry mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've a spring boot web application that can serve files from a static file location in server.
I've specified the location in properties file and using it to configure the `ResourceHandlerRegistry`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebApplication {

  @Value("${targetdirectory}")
  private String targetDirectory;

  @Bean
  WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        targetDirectory = StringUtils.appendIfMissing(targetDirectory, "/", "/");
        targetDirectory = StringUtils.prependIfMissing(targetDirectory, "file:/", "file:/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resourcetarget/**").addResourceLocations(targetDirectory);
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected. Now I have to dynamically set the resource location based on user input.
After the application is loaded, the user triggers an HTTP post request where he can specify the directory by which can be used as the resource location.
So after that any requests to the `/resourcetarget/**` should be mapped to the directory which the user specified. Following is the controller I have.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/locations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class MyController {

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleLocationSet(@RequestBody LocationDTO locationDto) {

    String newFileLocation = locationDto.getLocation();
    // How do I update the ResourceHandlerRegistry mapping for /resourcetarget/**
    // with the new location received here?

    return ResponseEntity.ok();
  }

}
```

How can I update the mapping for this dynamic location for a static resource url. Please help

Comment: did you get any solution for this use case? I am also facing the same problem. Please provide some input on how you have handled this case.

Comment: @VishwasUpadhyay No I didn't have a solution for this. But I manged to resolve my scenario by copying the file to the static location which I configured in the resource registry. My case is something like user specifies a local system location to which a file need to be written after some process. My web app need to get the file and make it downloadable by end user. So when ever I receive a file I copy it to the resource location of web app.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I am also configuring an external file path to for reference